# Finding the supremum of a function given its domain

Tags: real-analysis, functions, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f:R\to R $ be an increasing function. Take $S$, a non-empty   subset of R. Suppose s= sup$S$.Is $f(s)$ the supremum of$~~\left \{f(a)~|~a\in S\right\}$
I tried solving the question this way:
since Sup$S$ = s ;$\forall$a$\in S$, a≤s 
since f is increasing f(a)≤f(s) $\implies$f(s) is an upperbound for the given function.
I tried solving further to prove that Supremum is f(s) but things got messy. I finally got the answer after some complicated steps.I need to verify if the answer is correct please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take
$$f(x):=\begin{cases} x+1 & x\geq 0\\ x& x<0\end{cases}$$
And  $$ S=(-1,0)$$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\Rightarrow$ $\text{sup}(S)=0$

But
$$\text{Sup}\{f(a) |~~ a \in S\}=0\neq f(0)$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer..I completely forgot that it's not mentioned that the function is continuous

Comment: @LakshmiAnirudhPatibanda Then it is true